# Android: Hide below view under the center view on Scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-scrollview

I have center view that is below to the top bar and below that center view there is a scroll view that contains some images and text. Now what I want is when I scroll up the scroll view that scroll view should be hidden beneath the center view and there should be no scroll view part shown above the center view. Not all scroll view I want to hide it should be visible under the center view but it should not gone above the center view. Below are the Images that help in understanding what I want exactly. So any help will be highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

**Before Scroll:**

[image]

**After Scroll the part below the center view is visible only and that part comes under center view is hidden**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to place Center view over scroll view using Relative Layout and add a empty view on top of scroll view items with same height of center view so that your first item of scroll view is visible.